# Trying to write a method that is called and returns a string of asterisks in the same number of characters WITH boundaries

Tags: java, string

New to coding.. So far I have this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sOS1 = stringOfStars("a");
            System.out.println(sOS1);
        String sOS2 = stringOfStars("Hello, world!");
            System.out.println(sOS2);
        String sOS3 = stringOfStars("012345");
            System.out.println(sOS3);
}
    static String stringOfStars(String a) {
        String string = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
            string = string + "*";
        return string;
        
        // NEED ADDITIONAL CODE HERE

    }
}
```

Additional conditions I need:

1. Return a string of 3 asterisks if the character length is LESS than 3.
2. Return a string of 10 asterisks if the character length is GREATER than 10.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many different ways you can do this - beyond having lots of ifs.  Fundamentally you need to work out -

1. how many elements (stars) to output, AND then;
2. a way of producing them.

NOTE: string + string IN java is easy to write but can result in slower code, because of all the temporaries it introduces.  This article <[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-vs-stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer-in-java/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-vs-stringubilder-vs-stringbuffer-in-java/)> talks about the relative merits of String/StringBuilder/StringBuffer (if you are interested).

So for

Number of stars - one cool way for making an integer fit betweeen 2 values - in the mathematical sense [LOWER, HIGHER] - is to use min and max.

```
final int constrained = Math.max(LOWER, Math.min(HIGHER, input));
```

Producing the stars - [Apache Commons Lib StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat-java.lang.String-int-) is nice and succinct (pre-Java11).

```
StringUtils.repeat('*', 5);
```

Comment: you can also use `"*".repeat(5);`

Comment: I want the code in the same format and code I've been using just for consistency. Is it possible to explain in the way I gave my example code above?

Comment: Surely it's not hard to merge the two?  `return "*".repeat(Math.max(3, Math.min(10, a.length())));`

Answer (score 0):

Solution using simple if else blocks:

```
    static String stringOfStars(String a) {
        int count = 3;
        final int alen = a.length();
        if(alen > 10) {   //if more than 10
            count = 10;
        } else if(alen > 3) { //if between 3 and 10
            count = alen;
        }
        return "*".repeat(count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to onkar ruikar's answer:

```
static String stringOfStars(String a) {
    int count = 3;
    final int aLength = a.length();
    if (aLength > 3) {
        count = Math.min(aLength, 10);
    }
    return "*".repeat(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be to just replace any character with an asterisk using regular expressions

```
static String stringOfStars(String str){
    return str.replaceAll(".", "*");
}
```